# WordPress add custom link instead of custom page in Dashboard menu

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add custom menu item to the Dashboard menu, which will contain only link, not the whole page with the content.

For example: if I go to **Posts** and click on one of the posts titles to edit it - I'm redirected to the url something like: **mydomain/wp-admin/post.php?post=58&action=edit**. 
I want to create Dashboard menu link that goes directly to that edit page.

I've tried to use **add_menu_page** but this function adds a new page with the content to the dashboard menu, while all I need is to add dashboard menu item with the URL link (mydomain/wp-admin/post.php?post=58&action=edit) to go directly to edit a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for this you will need to use global $menu or $submenu variable and use it on admin_menu hook -

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'se20782231_admin_menu', 99);

function se20782231_admin_menu()
{
    global $menu, $submenu;

    // if submenu is under Posts menu
    $parent_menu = 'edit.php';
    $menu_name = '';
    $capability = '';
    $url = '';

    $submenu[$parent_menu][] = array( $menu_name, $capability, $url );
}
```

Comment: Shazzad, thanks for the quick reply, your solution works. I was trying to do a simple thing in a complicated way :)
Since (in my case) it was a custom post type, I've just printed the $menu array to see what is the array index of the menu item I wanted to change, and I've added the URL. Thanks.